# QMessageBox - url encoding/decoding

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I created a QMessageBox with an html link:

```
QTMessageBox msgBox(Utility::UI::topLevelWidget());

msgBox.setText("<a href=\"http://www.example.cz/?url=www%25www\">Link</a>");

msgBox.exec();
```

If I left click the link a new web browser tab opens.  The problem is that the url `http://www.example.cz/?url=www**%2525**www` is opened instead of `http://www.example.cz/?url=www**%25**www`

How do I prevent such behavior?

**UPDATE:** If I right click the link, choose "Copy link" and paste it into the browser, the link is ok.

Comment: I think the problem not came from here, post the method that open the tab in browser. Probably you encode once more the url ?

Comment: I change the code. If I right click the link, choose "Copy link" and paste it into the browser the link is ok.

Comment: So you want to prevent qt from translating "special" characters to html symbols (like `%` to `%25` or "space" to `%20`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `%` has the html encoding `%25`. So `%25` -> `%2525`.

Why does Qt encode the links automatically?

In the QMessageBox, there is a QLabel. The label uses the Qt::TextFormat Qt::AutoText by [default](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop). Therefore, it detects in your text, that it is html encoded and generates the link.

The QLabel sends the signal [linkActivated(const QString& link)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qlabel.html#linkActivated) or uses [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl), depending its the boolean [openExternalLinks](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop).

It seems, that the QMessageBox sets `openExternalLinks` to true.

Since the link will be used as input for a [QUrl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qurl.html), it will be parsed. That's the reason for the double encoding.

It is possible, to modify the behavior of `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` by using its static method `void QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler`. I implemented and tested it for the desired behavior:

```
MyUrlHandler urlHandler;
QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler( "http", &urlHandler, "handleUrl" );

QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText( "<a href=\"http://www.example.cz/?url=www%25www\">Link</a>" );
msgBox.show();
```

Using the class `MyUrlHandler`:

```
class MyUrlHandler : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyUrlHandler(QObject* parent=0):QObject(parent){}
public slots:
  void handleUrl(const QUrl &url)
  {
    QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl::fromEncoded( url.toString().toAscii() ) );
  }
};
```

The trick is simple, I set the link address directly to the `QUrl` instance as already valid url.

But unfortunately, it modifies the behavior globally.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much. QDesktopServices::unsetUrlHandler("https"); returns the handling behavior for the given scheme (https) to the default behavior.

Comment: Great. Yes, but it would be nicer, if there as an option to change the behavior for single instances. Nevertheless, if it fits for your needs, it's enough and I'm glad.